# If $0 \le \mu(A) < p < 1$, when is it true that there exists a measurable $B \supseteq A$ such that $\mu(B)=p$?

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mu)$ be a probability measure space and $A$ be a measurable subset of $X$ such that $0 \le \mu(A) < p < 1$.

## Question

When is it true that there exists a measurable $B \subseteq X$ such that $A \subseteq B$ and $\mu(B)=p$ ?

Comment: It is true if there are no atoms (that means: any subset of positive measure has a subset of positive but smaller measure.)

Comment: Ah, great thanks. I've just come across essentially this same fact at the moment, the so-called Sierpiński's Theorem, a kind of "Intermediate-Value Theorem" for measures.

Comment: (now I remember I wrote a short section in a wiki article on this:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(measure_theory)#Non-atomic_measures)

Comment: Yes, that's I was referring to in my comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An equivalent condition is that the probability space $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ is non-atomic, meaning that for every   $A\in \mathcal{M}$  with $\mu(A)>0$ there exists $B \in \mathcal{M}$ such that $B\subset A$ and $0<\mu(B)<\mu(A)$.

If  $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ is non-atomic then $\mu: \mathcal{M}\to [0,1]$ has a monotone section: that is, a map $E:[0,1]\to \mathcal{M}$ such that for all  $0\le t\le s\le1$ one has $\emptyset=E_0\subset E_t\subset E_s\subset E_1=X$  and  $\mu(E_t)=t$.

In fact, any "partial monotone section of $\mu$" (meaning a family $E:S\to \mathcal{M}$ as above, but with possibly smaller domain $S\subset [0,1]$) can be extended to a monotone section of $\mu$ (which in particular solves your problem).

I think this result is essentially due to Sierpiński; the proof uses the Zorn lemma on the set of graphs of the partial monotone sections of $\mu$, ordered by "extension" i.e. inclusion of graphs.

By the way, the maximality argument via Zorn lemma generalizes to a proof of the Lyapunov convexity theorem: if a $\mathbb{R}^n$ valued bounded vector measure  $\mu=(\mu_1,\dots,\mu_n)$ is non atomic (meaning, all $\mu_i$ are non-atomic bounded measures), then the range of $\mu$ is a compact convex set.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The question has been answered in the comments. Someone also downvoted it for the fun of it...

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the Chebychev convexity theorem. New good stuff.

Comment: Which minimal restrictions on my problem (i.e on a non-atomic measure) would remove the need for the (somewhat controversial) Zorn's lemma in the proof ?

Comment: What you want is to prove that a non-atomic probability measure is divisible, meaning the range is [0,1]. I guess the axiom of Dependent Choice is sufficient

Comment: What exactly was proved by Chebyshev?

Comment: Excuse me, I meant Lyapunov-- (fixed)

Comment: @PietroMajer For example, Axiom of choice is not needed for finite cartesian products. Agreed ? My question was, in my case what restrictions (if any) can be made to completely avoid any such axioms.

Comment: Of course restricting the class of measures may allow a more constructive proof, but I can only imagine cases in which the proof is also trivial (e.g. the Lebesgue measure on [0,1])

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An argument for Sierpiński's Intermediate Value Theorem for non-atomic measures without using Zorn's lemma (but possibly implicitly using countable axiom of choice, that I am not qualified to judge), it was told to me by Alexander Kuznetsov.

Denote for a measurable subset $C\subset X$ 
$$f(C,q):=\sup_{D\subset C,\mu(D)\leqslant q} \mu(D).$$
We want to prove that $f(C,q)=q$ if $\mu(C)\geqslant q$. Choose consecutively disjoint subsets $C_1,C_2,\ldots$ in $C$ so that $$
q-\sum_{j<i}\mu(C_j)\geqslant 
\mu(C_i)\geqslant f\left(C\setminus \cup_{j<i} C_j,q-\sum_{j<i}\mu(C_j)\right)-\frac 1i$$
for all $i=1,2,\ldots$. Then for $C_0=\cup C_i$ we have $\mu(C_0)=\sum \mu(C_i)\leqslant q$. Assume that $\mu(C_0)=q-a$ for $a>0$. The set $C\setminus C_0$ has positive measure, thus it contains a subset $E$ for which $0<\mu(E)<a$ (since our measure is non-atomic, the set $C\setminus C_0$ may be partitioned onto two subsets of positive measure, take the part with smaller measure and partition it again and so on). But it means that for large $i$ the choice of $C_i$ was not $1/i$-optimal in above sense: we could use $E$ instead. A contradiction.

Comment: Great constructive answer. Thanks!